# MySQL SELECT 1 trick?

Tags: mysql, database, select

What does **SELECT 1** do, first I saw it in open source library when querying the login attempts. And of course there isn't any '**1**' column name in the table. What is the purpose of asking nonexistent column instead any real one? speed?

Comment: `select 1` selects the **value** `1` - no column involved. You need to be more specific if that does not answer your question

Comment: it's for when you need to query for a row count, but don't want any of the data in the table. you can do `select 'some hardcoded fixed value' from sometable where somefield=somevalue`, just so you do get a result set.

Comment: thank you for the link. It's definitely a duplicate. Next time will try search better.

Comment: @MarcB: If you're after a row count, why would you want a resultset that contains many records instead of doing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sometable WHERE somefield=somevalue` and obtaining a resultset that contains exactly your desired integer?

Comment: @eggyal: mysql works properly with rowCount()-type functions, but not all dbs do.

Comment: @MarcB: Good to know!  Thanks.